# How does one craft a quill?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I don't think I've seen a SINGLE ONE in my playthrough so far, and I'm now in Act 2.

I've googled it and it seems that Feather + Knife is supposed to = Quill but this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoiler:

> By combining a knife and a feather.

If you can't find one:

> Just grab somebody's pillow while they aren't watching and slice it open with your knife. Plenty of feathers in there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a switchblade acts as a knife only sometimes; in this case I needed an actual dagger.